# ORA-00001 Unique constraint (string.string) violated

Tags: sql, oracle, plsqldeveloper

I have two tables that are identical to each other `t1` and `t2`, but `t2` has more data than `t1`.
I'm using this query to insert the missing data from `t2` to `t1`.

```
insert into t1
select * from t2
where not exist ( select * from t1
                  where t1.key1 = t2.key1
                  and t1.key2 = t2.key2)
```

When this query is run I get the: ORA-00001 Unique constraint (string.string) violated error.

The two tables have `key1` and `key2` as keys.

Since the only constraint is the two keys I don't understand why I'm getting that error.

EDIT: I noticed now in "Indexes" that there are 2 constraints both are of type unique.

The first one is: key1, random_column
The second one is: key2

sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: On what column is the unique constraint?

Comment: One of the keys it hits error. I've tried to only use one of the where statements which the error msg popsup on. But I get the same error message.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case there is a different understanding about the unique constraint, I am assuming that the unique constraint is one unique index on both fields.  If you have a unique constraint on key1 and a unique constraint on key2, then this will fail when there is a record in t1 with the same t2.key1 value, but a different t2.key2 value, because adding the record would result in two records in t1 with the same key1 value, which is forbidden by a unique constraint on key1.

If this is what you have, you need a unique index with both fields, rather than column constraints.

One possibility is that a value in t2 has a NULL key1 or a NULL key2.

In an expression, a NULL input always results in a NULL result which is considered false.

So, if t2 has a record with NULL key1 and a value of 'value2' for key2, then the where clause is evaluating

```
select * from t1
where t1.key1 = NULL and t1.key2 = 'value2'
```

This is not equivalent to

```
select * from t1
where t1.key1 is NULL and t1.key2 = 'value2'
```

instead t1.key1 = NULL will be untrue, the select will fail to ever return a result, the exist will be false and NOT(exist) will be true.  But if t1 already has a record like this, the unique constraint will fail.

So use this insert statement.

```
insert into t1
select * from t2
where not exist ( select * from t1
                  where (t1.key1 = t2.key1 or (t1.key1 is null and t2.key1 is null))
                  and (t1.key2 = t2.key2 or (t1.key2 is null and t2.key2 is null)))
```

Comment: If you want to check for equality and NULL values are equal, you can use `WHERE DECODE(t1.key1, t2.key1, 1) = 1` instead of `WHERE t1.key1 = t2.key1`.

Answer (score 0):

ideal case for use of *MINUS* result set operation

```
insert into t1
select * from t2
minus
select * from t1
```